# Как поменять текст на кнопке "Назад" в UINavigationBar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

По дефолту кнопка "Назад" в UINavigationBar представляет собой стрелку влево и тайтл предыдущего UIViewController. Нужно оставить стрелку, а текст на этой кнопке заменить на слово "Назад".

Таким способом это сделать не получается - кнопка никак не меняется:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Назад", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Таким способом получается изменить текст, но пропадает стрелка назад:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Назад", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Как можно и родную стрелку на кнопке Back оставить и текст заменить на свой?

Comment: Я делал вашим вторым способом, просто ещё добавлял изображение (`setImage` метод).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присвоить свое значение `backBarButtonItem` нужно в контроллере, *из которого* вы совершаете переход

Из [документации](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624958-backbarbuttonitem?language=objc):

> When this navigation item is immediately below the top item in the
>   stack, the navigation controller derives the back button for the
>   navigation bar from this navigation item.

То бишь кнопка берется из панели навигации контроллера, который находится непосредственно *под* самым верхним контроллером

Comment: NOTE: во viewDidLoad предыдущего контроллера нужно сделать вот так: let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(); backItem.title = "Назад"; navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem